# Renaming the array elements and updating it to the reducers using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

[image]

Hi Im trying to display the array with textbox for each element as shown in the image. The issue faced by me is when I enter the new name in textbox the same name is assigned for all the elements, so how do I overcome this issue, and save individual name for each current name. So this help in updating the database with new name.

```
class TablebackupName extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            tName: [pokemon, XXX, Batman],
            bName: [newname : ''],
        };
        this.onNameEdited = this.onNameEdited.bind(this);
    }


    onNameEdited(event) {
        this.state.bName.newname = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ bName: this.state.bName });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.tName.map(x =>

                 <input type="text" label={x} key={x.toString()} value={this.state.bName.newname} onChange={this.onNameEdited} />)}
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Use arrow functions instead of binding.

Comment: Why `react-redux` tag? It all looks like you are using local state.

Comment: I've started writing an answer - but I need to understand what you're trying to achieve to give you a proper solution.

Comment: @silicakes Actually I trying to rename the selected name from a table and update the new name to the backend. So I want the new name to be updated to the reducer so that the changes are made in the backend

Comment: checkout my answer then, it should be what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't mutate state directly:

   ```
   //wrong
   this.state.bName.newname = event.target.value;
   this.setState({ bName: this.state.bName });

   //right
   this.setState({ bName: {newName: event.target.value} });
   ```
2. You set the same state property for all of your map elements, so the state is shared.

I'd tackle it by setting defaultValue and then - on each update, just update the tName array with the new values.

```
export default class TablebackupName extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tName: ["pokemon", "XXX", "Batman"]
        };

        this.onNameEdited = (index) => (event) => {
            //using map to keep everything immutable
            let element = event.target;
            this.setState({
                tName: this.state.tName.map((val, i) => i === index ? element.value : val)
            })
        };
    }

    // creating a higher order function to get the right index for later use.
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.tName.map((x, index) => {
                                     return (
                                       <div key={index}>
                                          <label>{x}</label>
                                          <input type="text" defaultValue="" onKeyUp={this.onNameEdited(index)}/>
                                        </div>)


            })}
            </div>)
    }
}
```

webpackbin: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Ko7beSfn-FR__k94Q3k

Comment: I got error stating `setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition`

Comment: can line `this.onNameEdited = (index) => (event) =>` be replaced like this `  onNameEdited(index,event)`

Comment: no, but you can replace it with `this.onNameEdited.bind(index);` although i think it's less aesthetically pleasing.